# fishbone diagram using Python or graphviz

Tags: python, matplotlib, graphviz, diagram

I am trying to generate Fishbone Diagram (cause and effect diagram or Ishikawa diagram) with Python. Is there a way to make it more like standard fishbone chart?

```
from graphviz import Digraph

A=[('HW', 'Root'), ('SW', 'Root'),
  ('Electric', 'HW'), ('ink', 'HW'), ('windows', 'SW'), ('Drivers', 'SW'),
  ('Yellow', 'ink'), ('blue', 'ink'), ('pink', 'ink'),
  ('FE', 'Drivers'), ('BE', 'Drivers')]
e = Digraph()
e.attr(rankdir='LR')
for a in A:
    e.node(a[0])
    e.edge(a[0], a[1])
e.view()
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Would you show a sketch (hand drawn is fine) showing what you would like to see for your example - the "improved" result

Answer (score 1):

Doing such a thing with graphviz is really difficult as graphviz really has its own ideas on how to arrange things. Did you consider solving this with matplotlib? There is an [example creating a timeline](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/timeline.html) in matplotlib, that you could use as a basis and modify as needed.

Comment: Do you just need "primary" entries (my terminology) or do you also need to have "secondary"/"tertiary" entries ("bones off of bones")?  Pretty sure I can match the example shown above, but after that not so sure.

Answer (score 1):

As noted above, Fishbone Diagrams are outside the norm for Graphviz.  Below is a "pretty good" (eye of the beholder) version of the example diagram.  If you find it usable, I'll attach the input file & explain what is going on.  If not usable, please explain what you need.
Issues:

- line intersections are sloppy
- the result requires three steps

  - a `dot -Tdot` run
  - post-processing with GVPR (a Graphviz program) to create the wishbone "rake"
  - a `neato -n` run to create the visual file
- this does not handle secondary/tertiary relationships (bones-off-of-bones)
  The input file:

```
// non-directed graph, though directed would also work
graph W {
  // no splines
  graph [splines=line]
  // use underline-shape
  node [shape=underline]
  // first, we define the nodes & edges that make the centerline edge
  // note using standard ranking (top-to-bottom)
  // centerline is set on one rank
  // added a centerline attribute to make adding rak easier
  // dot ignores unknown attributes
  // gvpr program will use 
  {
    rank=same
    node [shape=rect style=invis centerline=true]  // mark centerline
    edge [headclip=false tailclip=false]
    p1 [group=g1]
    p2 [group=g2]
    p3 [group=g3]
    pstart:c -- p1:c --  p2:c --  p3:c
    pend [label=" Defect XXX" shape=plain style=solid]
    p3:c -- pend:w [dir=forward arrowhead=normal]
  }
  // define labels on top (min) rank
  // plain, not underlined
  {
    rank=min
    node [shape=plain]    
    measurements  materials personnel
  }
  // define leftmost "fishbone"
  // group attribte helps keep nodes aligned vertically
  {
  node [group=g1]
  measurements:se -- calibration:e -- microscopes:e -- inspectors:e
  // send this edge to the middle of the centerlin point
  inspectors:e -- p1:c  [headclip=false]
  }
  // define next "fishbone" to right
  {
  node [group=g2]
  materials:s--alloys:e--Lubricants:e--Suppliers:e 
  Suppliers:e -- p2:c [headclip=false]
  }
  // define rightmost "fishbone"
  {
  node [group=g3]
  personnel:s--shifts:e--training:e--operators:e--"another thing":e -- p3:c [headclip=false]
  }
  ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  // from here on, we are drawing edges out from centerline
  ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  // define labels on bottom (max) rank
  {
    rank=max
    node [shape=plaintext]
    Environment Methods Machines
  }
  {
  node [group=g1]
  p1 -- Humidity:e [tailclip=false]
  Humidity:e -- temperature:e -- Environment:n
  }
  {
  node [group=g2]
  p2 -- Angle:e  [tailclip=false]
  Angle:e --Engager:e-- Brake:e-- Methods:n 
  }
  {
  node [group=g3]
  p3 -- "blade wear":e  [tailclip=false]
  "blade wear":e -- speed:e -- Machines:n
  }
}
```

Run the above through dot and you get this - not that far off, but not a fishbone diagram:
[image]

Now, **wishbone.gvpr** - the **gvpr** (https://www.graphviz.org/pdf/gvpr.1.pdf) program that adds the fishbone rake:

```
BEGIN{
  int nIndx=0;
  float centerY=-999.9, dY, angleAdj, minY=9999, maxY=-9999;
  node_t Node[];
  graph_t theRoot, subG;
  void doErrs(string eString){
     printf(2, "Error:: %s\n", eString);
     print("// Error:: %s\n", eString); // temporary, for debugging
  }
}
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
N{
   Node[++nIndx]=$;
   if ((hasAttr($, "centerline")) && ($.centerline!="")){
      centerY=$.Y;
   }
   if ($.Y >maxY)
     maxY=$.Y;
   if ($.Y < minY)
     minY=$.Y;
}
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
END_G{
  if (centerY==-999.9){
      estr="\"centerline\" attribute is missing"; doErrs(estr);;
      exit(9);
  }
  $G.bb="";
  for (Node[nIndx]){
    print("//  pos before: ",Node[nIndx].pos);
    dY=Node[nIndx].Y-centerY;
    print("//  dY (1) : ", dY);
    // get absolute value
    if (dY<0){
      dY=-dY;
    }
    print("//  dY (2) : ", dY);
    Node[nIndx].pos=(string)(Node[nIndx].X - .25*dY) + "," + (string)Node[nIndx].Y;
    print("//  pos after: ", Node[nIndx].pos);
  }
}
```

The **gvpr** program adjusts the X coordinates
Then `neato -n` (https://graphviz.org/faq/#FaqDotWithNodeCoords) fixes the edges.
Finally the command line (Linux) that does it all - (if Windows does not support pipes, just send intermediate output to temporary files)

```
dot -Tdot myfile.gv |
gvpr -c -f wishbone.gvpr  |
neato -n -Tpng >myfile.png
```

Giving:
[image]

Whew!

Comment: I would say this a great representation of the graph. Looking forward to learning from the input file and the process of creation. Thank you!

Comment: The one thing I'd like added is the `Defect XXX` from the original diagram.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem and I have not yet found straight implementation for the Ishikawa diagram, so I implemented by myself using only matplotlib and numpy. Here's the code, maybe it is a bit "rusty" but works. Maybe it will be useful to someone else. Have a good coding!

```
# =============================================================================
# Importing
# =============================================================================
# Python Libraries
import numpy as np
#import pandas as pd
from pathlib import Path 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib

# =============================================================================
# AUX FUNCTIONS
# =============================================================================
def drawSpines(data:dict,ax:plt.Axes,parentSpine=None,alpha_ps:float=60.0,alpha_ss:float=0,recLevel=1,MAX_RECURSION_LEVEL:int=4,DEBUG=False): 
    #stop recursion if maximum level reached
    if recLevel > MAX_RECURSION_LEVEL:
        raise AttributeError('Max Recursion Level Reached')
    

    if isinstance(data, dict):
        # switch to correct angle depending on recursion level
        if recLevel % 2 != 0:
            alpha = alpha_ps
        else:
            alpha = alpha_ss
  
        if isinstance(parentSpine,matplotlib.lines.Line2D):
            #calculate parent data
            ([xpb,xpe],[ypb,ype]) = parentSpine.get_data()
        elif isinstance(parentSpine, matplotlib.text.Annotation):
            xpb,ypb = parentSpine.xy
            xpe,ype = parentSpine._x, parentSpine._y#parentSpine._arrow_relpos
        else:
            raise AttributeError('Wrong Spine Graphical Element')
            
        plen = np.sqrt((xpe-xpb)**2+(ype-ypb)**2)
        palpha = np.degrees(np.arctan2(ype-ypb,xpe-xpb))  
    
    
        # calculate spacing
        pairs = len(list(data.keys())) // 2 + len(list(data.keys())) % 2 +1 #calculate couple pairs, at least 1 pair to start at middle branch
        spacing = (plen) / pairs
        
        spine_count=0
        s=spacing
        #draw spine  
        for k in data.keys():
            # calculate arrow position in the graph
            if recLevel==1:# and spine_count <= 1: #fix first 2 spines spacing
                x_end = xpe-(s/1.5)*np.cos(np.radians(palpha))#0.9*xpe
                y_end = ype-s*np.sin(np.radians(palpha))
                
                x_start = x_end -s*np.cos(np.radians(alpha))
                y_start = y_end -s*np.sin(np.radians(alpha))
            else:
                x_end = xpe-s*np.cos(np.radians(palpha))
                y_end = ype-s*np.sin(np.radians(palpha))
                
                x_start = x_end -s*np.cos(np.radians(alpha))
                y_start = y_end -s*np.sin(np.radians(alpha))
            if DEBUG == True:
                print(f'k: {k}, x_start: {x_start}, y_start: {y_start}, x_end: {x_end}, y_end: {y_end}, alpha: {alpha} \n recLevel: {recLevel}, s:{s}, plen:{plen}, palpha:{palpha}')
            
            
            # draw arrow arc
            if recLevel==1:
                props = dict(boxstyle='round', facecolor='lightsteelblue', alpha=1.0)
                spine = ax.annotate(str.upper(k), xy=(x_end, y_end), xytext=(x_start, y_start),arrowprops=dict(arrowstyle="->",facecolor='black'),bbox=props,weight='bold')
            else:
                props = dict(boxstyle='round', facecolor='lavender', alpha=1.0)
                spine = ax.annotate(k, xy=(x_end, y_end), xytext=(x_start, y_start),arrowprops=dict(arrowstyle="->",facecolor='black'),bbox=props)
            # Call recursion to draw subspines
            drawSpines(data=data[k],ax=ax,parentSpine=spine,recLevel=recLevel+1)
    
            # next spine settings - same level
            alpha *= -1
            spine_count += 1
            if  spine_count %2 ==0:
                s= s+spacing 
    return None

def ishikawaplot(data,figSize=(20,10),left_margin:float=0.05,right_margin:float=0.05, alpha_ps:float=60.0,alpha_ss= 0.0,pd_width:int=0.1) -> plt.figure:  
    
    fig = plt.figure(figsize=figSize)
    ax  = fig.gca()
    ax.set_xlim(0,1.0)
    ax.set_ylim(0,1.0)
    
    ax.axis('off')
    #hide x-axis
    #ax.get_xaxis().set_visible(False)
    #hide y-axis
    #ax.get_yaxis().set_visible(False)
    
    #draw main spine
    mainSpine = ax.axhline(y=0.5,xmin=left_margin,xmax=1-right_margin-pd_width)
    #draw fish head
    props = dict(boxstyle='round', facecolor='wheat', alpha=1.0)
    ax.text((1-right_margin-pd_width), 0.5, str.upper(list(data.keys())[0]), fontsize=12,weight='bold',verticalalignment='center',horizontalalignment='left', bbox=props)
    #draw fish tail
    x = (0.0,0.0,left_margin)
    y = (0.5-left_margin,0.5+left_margin,0.5)
    ax.fill(x,y) #"b"
    
    #draw spines with recursion
    drawSpines(data=data[list(data.keys())[0]],ax=ax,parentSpine=mainSpine,alpha_ps = alpha_ps, alpha_ss = alpha_ss)
    
    plt.tight_layout()
    
    
    return fig

# =============================================================================
# Rooting
# =============================================================================
current_dir = Path(__file__).parent
output_path = current_dir / "Ishikawa.jpeg"


# =============================================================================
# USER DATA
# =============================================================================
data = {'problem': {'machine': {'cause1':''},
                    'process': {'cause2': {'subcause1':'','subcause2':''}
                               },
                    'man':     {'cause3': {'subcause3':'','subcause4':''}
                               },
                    # 'design':  {'cause4': {'subcause5':'','subcause6':''}
                    #            }
                    
                   }
       }


# =============================================================================
# MAIN CALL
# =============================================================================
if __name__ == '__main__':
    
    fig = ishikawaplot(data,figSize=(20,10))
    
    fig.show()
    
    fig.savefig(output_path, 
                     #dpi=800, 
                     format=None, 
                     #metadata=None,
                     bbox_inches=None, 
                     pad_inches=0.0,
                     facecolor='auto', 
                     edgecolor='auto',
                     orientation='landscape',
                     transparent=False,
                     backend=None)
```

Output:
[Ishikawa diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vVh8y.jpg)