# graphviz: rank a group of nodes to the right from another group of nodes

Tags: graphviz

I'm trying to separate all the green nodes in the image below to the right of the red nodes, as if there was an imaginary vertical line between them.

[image: output without clusters]

This is the current input file:

```
digraph G {
        rankdir="LR"
                subgraph cluster_2 {
                        "astn-serialize-string-res" [ color="green" ]
                }
                subgraph cluster_4 {
                        "pareto-lang-lib" [ color="red", penwidth=3 ]
                }
                subgraph cluster_5 {
                        graph[color="red"]
                        "astn-unmarshall-lib" [ color="red", penwidth=3 ]
                }
                subgraph cluster_6 {
                        graph[color="red"]
                        "astn-typedhandlers-lib" [ color="red", penwidth=3 ]
                }
                subgraph cluster_7 {
                        graph[color="red"]
                        "astn-tokenizer-lib" [ color="red", penwidth=3 ]
                }
                subgraph cluster_8 {
                        "astn-serializer-lib" [ color="red", penwidth=3 ]
                }
                subgraph cluster_9 {
                        graph[color="red"]
                        "astn-parser-lib" [ color="red", penwidth=3 ]
                }
                subgraph cluster_10 {
                        graph[color="red"]
                        "astn-mrshlschema-lib" [ color="red", penwidth=3 ]
                }
                subgraph cluster_11 {
                        graph[color="red"]
                        "astn-marshall-lib" [ color="red", penwidth=3 ]
                }
                subgraph cluster_12 {
                        graph[color="red"]
                        "astn-loader-lib" [ color="red", penwidth=3 ]
                }
                subgraph cluster_13 {
                        graph[color="red"]
                        "astn-ide-lib" [ color="red", penwidth=3 ]
                }
                subgraph cluster_14 {
                        graph[color="red"]
                        "astn-expect-lib" [ color="red", penwidth=3 ]
                }
                subgraph cluster_16 {
                        "astn-typedhandlers-api" [ color="green" ]
                }
                subgraph cluster_17 {
                        "astn-tokenconsumer-api" [ color="green" ]
                }
                subgraph cluster_18 {
                        "astn-serialize-string-api" [ color="green" ]
                }
                subgraph cluster_19 {
                        "astn-handlers-api" [ color="green" ]
                }
        "pareto-lang-lib--fountain-pen-lib" [label= "fountain-pen-lib"]
        "pareto-lang-lib" -> "pareto-lang-lib--fountain-pen-lib"
        "pareto-lang-lib" -> "astn-handlers-api"
        "pareto-lang-lib" -> "astn-expect-lib"
        "astn-unmarshall-lib" -> "astn-typedhandlers-api"
        "astn-unmarshall-lib" -> "astn-handlers-api"
        "astn-typedhandlers-lib" -> "astn-typedhandlers-api"
        "astn-typedhandlers-lib" -> "astn-tokenconsumer-api"
        "astn-typedhandlers-lib" -> "astn-handlers-api"
        "astn-typedhandlers-lib" -> "astn-expect-lib"
        "astn-typedhandlers-api" -> "astn-handlers-api"
        "astn-tokenizer-lib" -> "astn-tokenconsumer-api"
        "astn-serializer-lib" -> "astn-serialize-string-api"
        "astn-serializer-lib" -> "astn-handlers-api"
        "astn-serialize-string-res" -> "astn-serialize-string-api"
        "astn-parser-lib" -> "astn-tokenconsumer-api"
        "astn-parser-lib" -> "astn-handlers-api"
        "astn-mrshlschema-lib" -> "pareto-lang-lib"
        "astn-mrshlschema-lib" -> "astn-typedhandlers-api"
        "astn-mrshlschema-lib" -> "astn-handlers-api"
        "astn-marshall-lib" -> "astn-typedhandlers-api"
        "astn-marshall-lib" -> "astn-tokenconsumer-api"
        "astn-marshall-lib" -> "astn-parser-lib"
        "astn-loader-lib" -> "astn-unmarshall-lib"
        "astn-loader-lib" -> "astn-tokenizer-lib"
        "astn-loader-lib" -> "astn-parser-lib"
        "astn-loader-lib" -> "astn-mrshlschema-lib"
        "astn-loader-lib" -> "astn-expect-lib"
        "astn-ide-lib" -> "astn-typedhandlers-api"
        "astn-expect-lib" -> "astn-handlers-api"
}
```

I thought that adding clusters would solve the trick, but it messes up the layout:

[image: output with clusters]

This is the input with clusters:

```
digraph G {
        rankdir="LR"
        subgraph cluster_0 {
        }
        subgraph cluster_1 {
                subgraph cluster_2 {
                        "astn-serialize-string-res" [ color="green" ]
                }
        }
        subgraph cluster_3 {
                subgraph cluster_4 {
                        "pareto-lang-lib" [ color="red", penwidth=3 ]
                }
                subgraph cluster_5 {
                        graph[color="red"]
                        "astn-unmarshall-lib" [ color="red", penwidth=3 ]
                }
                subgraph cluster_6 {
                        graph[color="red"]
                        "astn-typedhandlers-lib" [ color="red", penwidth=3 ]
                }
                subgraph cluster_7 {
                        graph[color="red"]
                        "astn-tokenizer-lib" [ color="red", penwidth=3 ]
                }
                subgraph cluster_8 {
                        "astn-serializer-lib" [ color="red", penwidth=3 ]
                }
                subgraph cluster_9 {
                        graph[color="red"]
                        "astn-parser-lib" [ color="red", penwidth=3 ]
                }
                subgraph cluster_10 {
                        graph[color="red"]
                        "astn-mrshlschema-lib" [ color="red", penwidth=3 ]
                }
                subgraph cluster_11 {
                        graph[color="red"]
                        "astn-marshall-lib" [ color="red", penwidth=3 ]
                }
                subgraph cluster_12 {
                        graph[color="red"]
                        "astn-loader-lib" [ color="red", penwidth=3 ]
                }
                subgraph cluster_13 {
                        graph[color="red"]
                        "astn-ide-lib" [ color="red", penwidth=3 ]
                }
                subgraph cluster_14 {
                        graph[color="red"]
                        "astn-expect-lib" [ color="red", penwidth=3 ]
                }
        }
        subgraph cluster_15 {
                subgraph cluster_16 {
                        "astn-typedhandlers-api" [ color="green" ]
                }
                subgraph cluster_17 {
                        "astn-tokenconsumer-api" [ color="green" ]
                }
                subgraph cluster_18 {
                        "astn-serialize-string-api" [ color="green" ]
                }
                subgraph cluster_19 {
                        "astn-handlers-api" [ color="green" ]
                }
        }
        "pareto-lang-lib--fountain-pen-lib" [label= "fountain-pen-lib"]
        "pareto-lang-lib" -> "pareto-lang-lib--fountain-pen-lib"
        "pareto-lang-lib" -> "astn-handlers-api"
        "pareto-lang-lib" -> "astn-expect-lib"
        "astn-unmarshall-lib" -> "astn-typedhandlers-api"
        "astn-unmarshall-lib" -> "astn-handlers-api"
        "astn-typedhandlers-lib" -> "astn-typedhandlers-api"
        "astn-typedhandlers-lib" -> "astn-tokenconsumer-api"
        "astn-typedhandlers-lib" -> "astn-handlers-api"
        "astn-typedhandlers-lib" -> "astn-expect-lib"
        "astn-typedhandlers-api" -> "astn-handlers-api"
        "astn-tokenizer-lib" -> "astn-tokenconsumer-api"
        "astn-serializer-lib" -> "astn-serialize-string-api"
        "astn-serializer-lib" -> "astn-handlers-api"
        "astn-serialize-string-res" -> "astn-serialize-string-api"
        "astn-parser-lib" -> "astn-tokenconsumer-api"
        "astn-parser-lib" -> "astn-handlers-api"
        "astn-mrshlschema-lib" -> "pareto-lang-lib"
        "astn-mrshlschema-lib" -> "astn-typedhandlers-api"
        "astn-mrshlschema-lib" -> "astn-handlers-api"
        "astn-marshall-lib" -> "astn-typedhandlers-api"
        "astn-marshall-lib" -> "astn-tokenconsumer-api"
        "astn-marshall-lib" -> "astn-parser-lib"
        "astn-loader-lib" -> "astn-unmarshall-lib"
        "astn-loader-lib" -> "astn-tokenizer-lib"
        "astn-loader-lib" -> "astn-parser-lib"
        "astn-loader-lib" -> "astn-mrshlschema-lib"
        "astn-loader-lib" -> "astn-expect-lib"
        "astn-ide-lib" -> "astn-typedhandlers-api"
        "astn-expect-lib" -> "astn-handlers-api"
}
```

is there a way to achieve what I want?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using `rank=same`  "backwards" (figuratively).  Usually `rank=same` is part of the graph from the beginning, here we "eyeball" the original graph and guess at two new subgraphs that will produce the graph we want.  Pretty easy in this case, but a different, larger graph could have been much harder.

```
digraph G {
        rankdir="LR"
                subgraph cluster_2 {
                        "astn-serialize-string-res" [ color="green" ]
                }
                subgraph cluster_4 {
                        "pareto-lang-lib" [ color="red", penwidth=3 ]
                }
                subgraph cluster_5 {
                        graph[color="red"]
                        "astn-unmarshall-lib" [ color="red", penwidth=3 ]
                }
                subgraph cluster_6 {
                        graph[color="red"]
                        "astn-typedhandlers-lib" [ color="red", penwidth=3 ]
                }
                subgraph cluster_7 {
                        graph[color="red"]
                        "astn-tokenizer-lib" [ color="red", penwidth=3 ]
                }
                subgraph cluster_8 {
                        "astn-serializer-lib" [ color="red", penwidth=3 ]
                }
                subgraph cluster_9 {
                        graph[color="red"]
                        "astn-parser-lib" [ color="red", penwidth=3 ]
                }
                subgraph cluster_10 {
                        graph[color="red"]
                        "astn-mrshlschema-lib" [ color="red", penwidth=3 ]
                }
                subgraph cluster_11 {
                        graph[color="red"]
                        "astn-marshall-lib" [ color="red", penwidth=3 ]
                }
                subgraph cluster_12 {
                        graph[color="red"]
                        "astn-loader-lib" [ color="red", penwidth=3 ]
                }
                subgraph cluster_13 {
                        graph[color="red"]
                        "astn-ide-lib" [ color="red", penwidth=3 ]
                }
                subgraph cluster_14 {
                        graph[color="red"]
                        "astn-expect-lib" [ color="red", penwidth=3 ]
                }
                subgraph cluster_16 {
                        "astn-typedhandlers-api" [ color="green" ]
                }
                subgraph cluster_17 {
                        "astn-tokenconsumer-api" [ color="green" ]
                }
                subgraph cluster_18 {
                        "astn-serialize-string-api" [ color="green" ]
                }
                subgraph cluster_19 {
                        "astn-handlers-api" [ color="green" ]
                }

        {rank=same
          "astn-unmarshall-lib" "astn-expect-lib" "astn-serializer-lib"
        }
        {rank=same
           "astn-tokenconsumer-api"  "astn-typedhandlers-api"  "astn-serialize-string-api"   "astn-serialize-string-res" 
        }

        "pareto-lang-lib--fountain-pen-lib" [label= "fountain-pen-lib"]
        "pareto-lang-lib" -> "pareto-lang-lib--fountain-pen-lib"
        "pareto-lang-lib" -> "astn-handlers-api"
        "pareto-lang-lib" -> "astn-expect-lib"
        "astn-unmarshall-lib" -> "astn-typedhandlers-api"
        "astn-unmarshall-lib" -> "astn-handlers-api"
        "astn-typedhandlers-lib" -> "astn-typedhandlers-api" 
        "astn-typedhandlers-lib" -> "astn-tokenconsumer-api"
        "astn-typedhandlers-lib" -> "astn-handlers-api"
        "astn-typedhandlers-lib" -> "astn-expect-lib"
        "astn-typedhandlers-api" -> "astn-handlers-api"
        "astn-tokenizer-lib" -> "astn-tokenconsumer-api"
        "astn-serializer-lib" -> "astn-serialize-string-api"
        "astn-serializer-lib" -> "astn-handlers-api"
        "astn-serialize-string-res" -> "astn-serialize-string-api"
        "astn-parser-lib" -> "astn-tokenconsumer-api"
        "astn-parser-lib" -> "astn-handlers-api"
        "astn-mrshlschema-lib" -> "pareto-lang-lib"
        "astn-mrshlschema-lib" -> "astn-typedhandlers-api"
        "astn-mrshlschema-lib" -> "astn-handlers-api"
        "astn-marshall-lib" -> "astn-typedhandlers-api"
        "astn-marshall-lib" -> "astn-tokenconsumer-api"
        "astn-marshall-lib" -> "astn-parser-lib"
        "astn-loader-lib" -> "astn-unmarshall-lib"
        "astn-loader-lib" -> "astn-tokenizer-lib"
        "astn-loader-lib" -> "astn-parser-lib"
        "astn-loader-lib" -> "astn-mrshlschema-lib"
        "astn-loader-lib" -> "astn-expect-lib"
        "astn-ide-lib" -> "astn-typedhandlers-api"
        "astn-expect-lib" -> "astn-handlers-api"
}
```

Giving:
[image]

Comment: Thank you for this solution. It looks the way I want it to look. There is one issue with it (which I don't know if it can be resolved easily); the graph is generated, the algorithm that produces it is unaware of which exact nodes should be on the same rank. It can not be all of the green ones on the same rank for example. Do you have any suggestions for a method that does not require to figure this out?

Comment: Surprising difficult.  "Best" suggestion is to write a post-processor to "slide" all the green nodes over until they are "right of" all the red nodes.  Not a perfect algorithm, but write once & reuse.  Could be written in python, gvpr, ...  Part of the algorithm already exists in Graphviz source (see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51348536/fishbone-diagram-using-python-or-graphviz/72205504#72205504)

Comment: Thanks! I already was thinking of the postprocessing. In that way it is quite easy. Just count the amount of 'ancestors' a node has within its group. But I was a bit reluctant because perhaps there was a straightforward graphviz solution. Now that you confirm my suspicion, I know what to do.