# Fishbone diagram on python

Tags: python, graphviz, diagram, dot

I was trying to create a Fishbone Diagram also known as cause and effect diagram or Ishikawa diagram on Python. Can anyone help me to make it more like standard fishbone diagram? im not really familiarized with the dot language, and the script i used was from a previous post in the forum

[This is what i have done so far](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8u9HC.png)
[And this i what i want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ebPn3.png)

```
       graph W {
      graph [splines=line]
      node [shape=underline]
      {
        rank=same
        node [shape=rect style=invis centerline=true]
        edge [headclip=false tailclip=false]
        p1 [group=g1]
        p2 [group=g2]
        p3 [group=g3]
        pstart:c -- p1:c --  p2:c --  p3:c
        pend [label=" Defect XXX" shape=plain style=solid]
        p3:c -- pend:w [dir=forward arrowhead=normal]
      }
      {
        rank=min
        node [shape=plain]    
        measurements  materials personnel
      }
      {
      node [group=g1]
      measurements:se -- calibration:e -- microscopes:e -- inspectors:e
      inspectors:e -- p1:c  [headclip=false]
      }
      {
      node [group=g2]
      materials:s--alloys:e--Lubricants:e--Suppliers:e 
      Suppliers:e -- p2:c [headclip=false]
      }
      {
      node [group=g3]
      personnel:s--shifts:e--training:e--operators:e--"another thing":e -- p3:c [headclip=false]
      }
      {
        rank=max
        node [shape=plaintext]
        Environment Methods Machines
      }
      {
      node [group=g1]
      p1 -- Humidity:e [tailclip=false]
      Humidity:e -- temperature:e -- Environment:n
      }
      {
      node [group=g2]
      p2 -- Angle:e  [tailclip=false]
      Angle:e --Engager:e-- Brake:e-- Methods:n 
      }
      {
      node [group=g3]
      p3 -- "blade wear":e  [tailclip=false]
      "blade wear":e -- speed:e -- Machines:n
      }
    }
   

 BEGIN{int nIndx=0;
  float centerY=-999.9, dY, angleAdj, minY=9999, maxY=-9999;
  node_t Node[];
  graph_t theRoot, subG;
  void doErrs(string eString){
     printf(2, "Error:: %s\n", eString);
     print("// Error:: %s\n", eString); // temporary, for debugging
  }
}
N{
   Node[++nIndx]=$;
   if ((hasAttr($, "centerline")) && ($.centerline!="")){
      centerY=$.Y;
   }
   if ($.Y >maxY)
     maxY=$.Y;
   if ($.Y < minY)
     minY=$.Y;
}

    END_G{
      if (centerY==-999.9){
          estr="\"centerline\" attribute is missing"; doErrs(estr);;
          exit(9);
      }
      $G.bb="";
      for (Node[nIndx]){
        print("//  pos before: ",Node[nIndx].pos);
        dY=Node[nIndx].Y-centerY;
        print("//  dY (1) : ", dY);
    
        if (dY<0){
          dY=-dY;
        }
        print("//  dY (2) : ", dY);
        Node[nIndx].pos=(string)(Node[nIndx].X - .25*dY) + "," + (string)Node[nIndx].Y;
        print("//  pos after: ", Node[nIndx].pos);
      }
    }
```

Comment: Please show your code as [formatted text](/help/formatting). Screenshots are okay for actual images such as your diagram, but having code as text allows us to copy it into our environment to test our suggestions instead of having to transcribe it all.

Comment: Sorry my bad, i just edited my post

Answer (score 0):

This has been answered here: [fishbone diagram using Python or graphviz](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51348536/fishbone-diagram-using-python-or-graphviz)

All in all, I suggest using **pikchr** (https://pikchr.org/home/doc/trunk/homepage.md)

Comment: Hi, i was actually trying with your script but i seems theres an error during the second part                                                                                                                           
 BEGIN{int nIndx=0;
  float centerY=-999.9, dY, angleAdj, minY=9999, maxY=-9999;
  node_t Node[];
  graph_t theRoot, subG;
  void doErrs(string eString){
     printf(2, "Error:: %s\n", eString);
     print("// Error:: %s\n", eString); // temporary, for debugging.

Comment: That gvpr program still works for me. What error do you get? Also what version of gvpr? (gvpr -V) and what OS? (windows, linux, ...)

Comment: it says this Expected “;”, “<“, “\”, “edge” , “graph”,  “node”, “subgraph”, “{“,”}”,  NUMBER or UNICODE_STRING BUT “,” found. And i tried doing it on jupyter notebook, but i didnt know how to make it work so ive been using these 2 online sites of graphviz http://magjac.com/graphviz-visual-editor/   https://dreampuf.github.io/GraphvizOnline/ by the way im in iOS

Comment: Ahh!  The "gvpr program" uses a different language (gvpr, not dot).  I don't think there are any web-based implementations of the gvpr "compiler".  So, either install Graphviz on your computer (http://www.graphviz.org/download/) it includes gvpr, accept the horizontal/vertical version of your graph, or forget Graphviz entirely and try pikchr (<< my best suggestion)